# Modulenotfound no module named 'google'

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am able to run the following command in google-colab notebook:

```
from google.collab import drive
```

But when I try to run it on a local jypter notebook. It will generate an error.
It generates error like

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
```

Google Collab should work so that the codes below cells can work

Answer (score 0):

You have a spelling error, run the block below in Colab to import drive:

`from google.colab import drive`