# Jupyter notebook: " No module named 'google.colab'", after having updated Anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter, google-colaboratory

### yesterday I had the bad idea to update Anaconda (the system was asking for it). Now, I cannot use Jupyter Notebook anymore:(
Below is the error I have when I am trying to mount the drive:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

### --

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 from google.colab import drive
      2 drive.mount('/content/drive')

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.colab'
--


(Looking at the answer to the 1st question below) I tried to re-install google.colab: "pip install google-colab", but it fails. Below is the partial output (I put "..." when I cut):
--
...
Collecting pandas~=0.24.0 (from google-colab)
  Using cached pandas-0.24.2.tar.gz (11.8 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): still running...
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
`  [324 lines of output]
  C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dnzbmumm\pandas_2bb5dd525f08419f83f59a4ca511da28\setup.py:12: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
    import pkg_resources
  C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dnzbmumm\pandas_2bb5dd525f08419f83f59a4ca511da28\setup.py:50: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
    _CYTHON_INSTALLED = ver >= LooseVersion(min_cython_ver)
  warning: pandas\_libs\algos_take_helper.pxi:89:4: The 'IF' statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future Cython version. Consider using runtime conditions or C macros instead. See https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/4310
...
```

--

Comment: Isn't that meant to be run on Google Colab? Not in the local Jupyter you installed via Anaconda? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76973769/8508004). Or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56507628/8508004). Minor: Also your text seems wrong: " I cannot use Jupyter Notebook anymore". Can you run `print("Hello World.")` in Jupyter?  If so then you can use Jupyter and your text should be edited to be accurate.

Comment: Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52300696/8508004).

Comment: In your update, you say "Before that update, everything was working fine." What specifcally was working? Like I said above, Jupyter is working on your machine if you can run simple Python. (Does `2 + 2` work?) The example you show is meant to be run in Google Colaboratory. Unclear how it would have worked. For example, in theory based on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68134466/8508004) you can run `%conda install -c conda-forge google-colab` in your local notebook and then you'll probably hit a different problem as spelled out in the comment below that. You should also consult ...

Comment: <continued> [an additional answer on that page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52621170/8508004) telling you that you want to run that in Google Collaboratory and not on your local computer. Plus see [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleColab/comments/152e6f0/how_do_i_mount_google_drive_on_a_local_runtime/) where it says, "This is not possible we only bundle the drive auth piece with our managed runtimes".